# How to configure multiple trunks in asterisk?

Tags: asterisk, sip

I have two accounts at ovh for my sip trunks.
First is a classic sip & second is a sip trunk.

In my sip.conf:

```
[general]
language=fr
bindport=5060
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
srvlookup=yes
canreinvite=no
defaultexpiry=3600
registertimeout=30
registerattempts=0
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allowguest=no
alwaysauthreject=yes
nat=yes
autocreatepeer=yes

register => 0033972XXXXXX:PASS1@sip.ovh.fr
register => 0033972YYYYYY:PASS2@siptrunk.ovh.net

[trunk-test]
disallow=all
type=friend
secret=PASS2
host=siptrunk.ovh.net
fromdomain=sip.ovh.fr;siptrunk.ovh.net
fromuser=0033972YYYYYY
username=0033972YYYYYY
nat=yes;force_rport,comedia
context=depuis-ovh
insecure=port,invite
qualify=yes
dtmfmode=inband
allow=ulaw

[vers-ovh]
disallow=all
type=friend
secret=PASS1
host=sip.ovh.fr
fromdomain=sip.ovh.fr
fromuser=0033972XXXXXX
username=0033972XXXXXX
nat=yes
context=ManageOperator
insecure=invite,port
qualify=yes
dtmfmode=inband
allow=ulaw
```

In my extensions.conf

```
[general]
static=yes
writeprotect=no
clearglobalvars=no

[globals]

[depuis-ovh]
exten => s, 1, Answer()
exten => s, n, AGI(NPCallCenterAsterisk/agi/app,services/42/country/EN)
exten => s, n, Hangup()

[ManageOperator]
exten => s, 1, Answer()
exten => s, n, AGI(NPCallCenterAsterisk/agi/app.php,manageOperator);
exten => s, n, Hangup()
```

When I call `0033972YYYYYY`, it works fine. The "depuis-ovh" context calls the AGI.
But when I call `0033972XXXXXX`, the call gets hung up immediately.

Do you have some ideas what the issue is?

NOTE: `0033972XXXXXX` & `0033972YYYYYY` works fine separately, when only one of them is configured.

Answer (score 2):

Should be `type=peer` so matching is done on host/IP only. Insecuring the invite on `type=friend` is just asking to get hacked because it disables password checking on inbound calls to your box, and all they have to get right is a username and they're in.

Get rid of `nat=yes` because it doesn't do what you think, as it is designed to help if the other end is behind NAT, not the other way around. Chances are good, that your provider doesn't rewrite the source port on their routers, so getting rid of the `insecure=port` buys a bit more security.

If you're going to `Inband` the `dtmf`, do it from your phone/ATA to your Asterisk box, then let your Asterisk box translate back to RFC back to your provider. The reason usually for setting `Inband` in the first place is usually because some `PAP2` models were poor at filtering out `dtmf` from the audio resulting in doubled digits being read at the far end.

Answer (score 0):

If you have insecure=invite, first peer with matched address will be choosed.

So you have option remove insecure-invite or just live with knowledge, that all request from same ip will go first trunk context(you can for example add number in that context)

Comment: When I remove invite asterisk give me
 WARNING[14978]: chan_sip.c:14895 check_auth: username mismatch, have <trunk-test>, digest has <anonymous>

Comment: Sorry, you have enable sip debug and consult your provider support WITH debug

Comment: I set the sip debug mode with command: sip set debug on

But when I call 0033972XXXXXX the dump is empty :'(
However when I call 0033972YYYYYY it dump correctly.

Comment: If dump empty, that mean provider not deliver call

Answer (score -1):

I setup a Asterisk server to, I have one SIP and one SIP Trunk, when I configure both of these each time only one is callable.
It seems to be always the SIP Trunk, my configuration is the same as Pierre-Luc ..

I wonder if it can be a port issue ? I mean, maybe each sip [ trunk ] must be assigned to a different port ?

I don't really fully understand what you mean arheops, can you detail your answer please ?

Comment: No, asterisk can't work on two ports. Why you answer if you no experience?

Comment: I'm just joining the conversation because I'm facing the same problem, I'm asking, not answering.

Comment: If so, you should use comments, not answer section. Question is simple. Asterisk determine which peer to use by IP ADDRESS. Provider's server also may have limit for number of registration per ip address. So if you have 2 peers with same address it works  bad.